# Linux equivalent of taskkill

Tags: linux, taskkill

What is the Linux equivalent of this command?

```
taskkill /F /IM myStupidProcess.exe /T
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`kill -9 pid_of_process`

or

`killall -KILL myStupidProcess`

Comment: Hi. thanks. Could you let me know whether this will kill the child processes also? Equivalent of the /T.

Comment: I googled for this, found http://morningcoffee.io/killing-a-process-and-all-of-its-descendants.html , which seems to indicate that it does *not* kill the child processes. It covers some options on how to pursue them, though.

Comment: So as I understand, since it is an equivalent of `kill -9`, `taskkill` is killing process without allowing it to properly perform clean-up process (like removing temporary files). Is there any other option to kill process on Windows?